# Values are not showing on chart graph swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using [chart](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library to plot graph in swift. I want to show below values on LineChartView.
My values are as follows.

1) x: 0.0 y: 0.62020133693747

2) x: 0.0 y: 0.62020133693747

3) x: 0.0 y: 0.62020133693747

4) x: 8500.0 y: 0.62020133693747

5) x: 8500.0 y: 0.925703706122449

6) x: 9000.0 y: 0.925703706122449

7) x: 9000.0 y: 1.43307403327373

8) x: 9500.0 y: 1.43307403327373

9) x: 9500.0 y: 0.37799568

10) x: 9500.0 y: 0.37799568

11) x: 9500.0 y: 0.37799568

12) x: 9000.0 y: 0.37799568

13) x: 9000.0 y: 0.269996914285714

14) x: 8500.0 y: 0.269996914285714

15) x: 8500.0 y: 0.239997257142857

16) x: 6000.0 y: 0.239997257142857

17) x: 6000.0 y: 0.219552079597251

18) x: 0.0 y: 0.219552079597251

19) x: 0.0 y: 0.453594816

20) x: 0.0 y: 0.453594816

From these values the expected graph is:

[image: Expected Graph]

But when I am using [chart](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library I am getting the following graph:

[image: Current Graph]

It seems that the library is not able to plot the last values.

I have tried various setting but it didn't solve my issue.

My Code:

```
`func updateChartValues(arrLineCDE: Array<ChartDataEntry>) -> (LineChartDataSet) {

let Xvalues: [Double] = [/*All My X values are here*/]
let Yvalues: [Double] = [/*All My Y values are here*/]
var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = Array()

for (i, x) in Xvalues.enumerated() {
    entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Xvalues[i], y: Yvalues[i], data: UIImage(named: "icon", in: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder), compatibleWith: nil)))
}
self.dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "Depth vs. FV")
self.dataSet.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.cubicBezier
return dataSet
}`
```

Line Chart Sttings

```
`func setLineChartProperty(lineChartView lcv: LineChartView) {
//Line Chart Setting:
// lcv.delegate = self
lcv.setViewPortOffsets(left: 44.0, top: 30.0, right: 44.0, bottom: 44.0)
lcv.backgroundColor = darkBlueColor
lcv.chartDescription?.enabled = false
lcv.dragEnabled = false
lcv.setScaleEnabled(false)
lcv.pinchZoomEnabled = false
lcv.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false

lcv.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: CGFloat(12.0))!
lcv.xAxis.setLabelCount(6, force: false)
lcv.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
lcv.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
lcv.xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.white
lcv.xAxis.gridColor = UIColor.white
lcv.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
lcv.xAxis.axisMaximum = 10000
lcv.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0

lcv.leftAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: CGFloat(12.0))!
lcv.leftAxis.setLabelCount(6, force: false)
lcv.leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
lcv.leftAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChart
lcv.leftAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.white
lcv.leftAxis.gridColor = UIColor.white
lcv.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true

lcv.legend.horizontalAlignment = .right
lcv.legend.verticalAlignment = .bottom
lcv.legend.orientation = .horizontal
lcv.legend.drawInside = true
lcv.legend.form = .square
lcv.legend.formSize = 8.0
lcv.legend.formToTextSpace = 4.0
lcv.legend.xEntrySpace = 6.0

lcv.xAxis.enabled = true
lcv.rightAxis.enabled = false
lcv.leftAxis.enabled = true
lcv.legend.enabled = true
lcv.legend.textColor = UIColor.white
lcv.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)

}`
```

Comment: show me the code

Comment: @a-n-i-k-e-t Edit your question and add your code there, not in the comments.

Comment: Its done can u check

Comment: Would you please debug on your side? As the line starts turning around, there is no obvious reason to not draw the last 6 value pairs, you can first add some breakpoints at `drawDataSets` in line chart renderer, to see if all your missing values are there, and if the loop condition mets.

Comment: Yes, I did, am getting all values in the dataset. But I don't have any idea why it's not printing. I have opened this issue on GitHub also. I am not sure is there value range setting or something similar? don't know? still, the problem is not fixed!